# Issues with installation LTTNG for fedora22

Tags: lttng

using: 4.2.8-200.fc22.x86_64

I have a lot of issues with installing latest package of fedora's lttng.

I have installed the latest version available for fedora as for 29/6/16.

Available Packages
Name        : lttng-tools
...
Version     : 2.6.0

whereas the latest available for other distributions is 2.8.0

http://git.lttng.org/?p=lttng-modules.git;a=shortlog;h=refs/heads/stable-2.8

as for fedora lttng-modules need to be installed manually.
none or the 2.5 through 2.6.1 are compiling.
 error: implicit declaration of function ‘__get_cpu_var’

and 2.6.3 report 
Can't read private key
for each module and reports
depmod: WARNING: /lib/modules/4.2.8-200.fc22.x86_64/extra/probes/lttng-probe-x86-exceptions.ko needs unknown symbol lttng_pid_tracker_lookup

none of the modules are available at insmod.

trying 2.8.0 modules result 
reports

Error: Kernel tracer ABI version (2.1) is not compatible with expected ABI major version (1.*)

second attempt result with the following.
lttng (create, enable, start, stop, view) result with no results.

Is there any plans you guys know of for further support for fedora beyond 2.6?
any Ideas for how can I make lttng works for my 22 fedora.
(not upgrading to fedora 24 due to performance degradation )

Regards,
Nir.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently taken over the maintenance of the lttng packages in Fedora, F25 will ship with the latest lttng 2.8 packages. As for F22, you best option would be to try to rebuild the F25 sources packages on F22. For the kernel modules you can use this source package intended for RHEL7 : http://packages.efficios.com/rhel/7/SRPMS/latest/lttng-modules/lttng-modules-2.8.0-1.el7.src.rpm

Hope it helps, cheers.

Comment: Michael Jeanson, thanks for taking this into your responsibility,
I will try it as soon as it released.
good luck.